# Network stream between Android and C#

Tags: c#, android

I want to create a client server based application.
With the client running on android and the server on C#.

My main problem is that it seems like i cant send messages from my server 
to my client.

I am using a TcpListener to capture a socket,

```
TcpListener sSocket = new TcpListener(5555);
Socket soc = sSocket.AcceptSocket();
```

and to send and recive im using the built in functions from the socket,

```
Byte[] currentReciveMessage;
socket.Receive(currentReciveMessage, SocketFlags.None);

String message = "HEY";
byte[] tmp = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
socket.Send(tmp, tmp.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

The problem is at the send side. I can receive message from the client but not send them.

The implantation of the reader from on the android side uses a BufferedReader,

```
sock = new Socket(serverAddr,port);
isR=new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
reader=new BufferedReader(isR);
```

and im reading from it like this.

```
String tmp = "";
while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
   tmp +=(reader.readLine());
}
```

But the problem is that I don't receive anything.

My question is, does anything seems strange to you?
Do you see anything that could be wrong with using this 
method?

Hope you can help me or give me a hint on whats wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing readLine, you will need to send the new line character \n from the server.